# Is extending a factory class an anti-pattern?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, factory, builder

Let's say that there is a `CarFactory class` and it is extended by `classes` like `FerrariFactory` and `VolvoFactory`. Each class has a `List<Car> build(List<CarPart>)` method

Now a requirement comes up that for any given `List<CarPart>` the optimal list of Cars must be returned.

Would it be an anti-pattern to put the logic in `CarFactory.build`?

```
CarFactory
    List<Car> build(List<CarPart>)
        split car part list into optimal car part sub-lists for each factory
        instantiate car factories and pass in the sub-list of car parts
        return collection of cars
```

Or would it be better to have another class like a `CarBuilder` class does this?. Is there a typical design pattern I can use to solve this problem?

Comment: There is no `virtual` in Java.

Comment: What do you mean by *optimal*?

Comment: Each part is labeled by the type of factory it is supposed to go to e.g. 'VolvoPart', or 'FerrariPart'

Comment: What you do inside a factory method doesn't really matter/is irrelevant (validation and/or optimization is actually common) as long as your factory provides the use it was designed for: decouple the type of object that's to be instantiated. As for instantiating car factories within the car factory's method, what's the purpose of using a factory there?

Comment: @VinceEmigh I see now that FerrariFactory isn't a true 'factory' because it is not decoupling the type of object that is to be instantiated; it will always return a Ferrari type car. The reason I have this structure is because the CarFactory sub classes all share certain methods for building cars, so it seemed like a good way to reduce code duplication.

Comment: I think maybe the builder pattern would be a better pattern to use here https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder. The 'Director' would parse the car parts and instantiate different car 'Builder's (e.g. VolvoBuilder or FerrariBuilder) to build the appropriate cars.

Answer (score -1):

I think, any logic in builder is anti pattern, because, instantiate new object should be very fast and quite.
I mean, that maximum code in builder - only one operator `new ClassName(params...)`.
if you need any logic - move it to new small class, which solve this:

```
List <Car> CarFactory.build (params...) {
  return new CarLogicSolver(params).list();
}
```

you can see great examples in java.util.stream.Collectors.toSet, .toList, toMap etc.